# What if I want Oracle SQL to GROUP BY this but not that?

Tags: oracle

This is what I get previously from another SQL code:

```
    Customer Id week_ending Purchase Id Price
    1234    2/28/2015   8604220 15
    1234    2/28/2015   8604220 13.75
    1234    2/28/2015   8604220 12.95
    1234    2/28/2015   8604220 18.95
    567890  8/15/2015   6376243 5.15
    567890  8/15/2015   6376243 0.89
    567890  8/15/2015   6376243 3.99
    567890  8/15/2015   6376243 2.3
    1234    1/24/2015   8824241 0.99
    1234    1/24/2015   8824241 3.99
    1234    1/24/2015   8824241 3.89
```

Now I want to sum the price by Purchase ID since it is unique for every of our customer's order but I don't want my SQL to think and sum it by Customer ID (since each customer could order multiple times with multiple Purchase ID). Following is my code that I wrote but I'm afraid that it would sum them by customer_id. How do I avoid this mistake of double accounting? Thanks in advance!

```
    WITH example AS(SELECT
          customer_id
          ,MAX(nvl(promised_arrival_day, ship_day)) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id) AS ship2_day
          ,purchase_id
          ,SUM(price) AS order_size
        FROM
          my_table 

        GROUP BY 
         customer_id
         ,MAX(nvl(promised_arrival_day, ship_day)) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_purchase_id) 
         ,purchase_id)
    SELECT 
    example.customer_id
     ,TO_CHAR(example.ship2_day + (7-TO_CHAR(example.ship2_day,'d')),'MM-DD-YYYY') AS week_ending
   ,example.purchase_id
    ,example.order_size
  FROM 
   example;
```

Comment: If this is oracle why tagged mysql and MS SQL Server

Comment: You've told the database to SUM(price) grouped by CUSTOMER_ID, MAX(...whatever...), and PURCHASE_ID. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: There's no double counting -- you get one row per unique combination of customer_id and purchase_id, with the correct sum for that combination of values.

Comment: I believe you are *way* over thinking this. @mathew-mcpeak has the answer, and it's simple.

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
SELECT customer_id, purchase_id, sum(price)
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY customer_id, purchase_id
```

Each record will be counted only once.  It doesn't do any "double accounting" as you say.

You will get one record for each unique combination of customer_id/puchase_id in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data, I would do something like.

```
 with tbl as(
      -- query by which you are getting     dataset in example
     )
 select customer_id,purchase_id, sum(price) as total_price from tbl
 group by purchase_id,customer_id
```

Comment: How do I still keep customer_id with this? Thanks!

Comment: I can't run it to verify right now, but can you use something like "select purchase_id, customer_id, sum(price) as total_price from tbl
 group by purchase_id,customer_id "  and let me know if you get correct result. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I checked it and it is giving unique set of customer_id and purchase_id.This query would give same result as given by Matthew. I will edit my answer to add customer_id